# Book for probability to be useful in machine learning

Tags: reference-request

How would you recommend Sheldon Ross' **A First Course In Probability** for the purpose mentioned in the title? (i.e. to be of significant use while studying machine learning)

An advice book on Linear Algebra & Statistics & whatever it takes to understand or think Machine Learning is also sought. Have a very little idea of above topics & I'm going to redo everything mentioned above by myself. So will you try to advise on study plan (kinda), too? 
**Thank you**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a marvelous book: [The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction, Second Edition (Springer Series in Statistics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576). I believe you'll get what you need in first instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely recommend the book by Witten et al. [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html) are a list of books for probability and at the bottom is that book that describes machine learning in a very easy to read manner.